# Is there any default time-out for file locks on Windows network shares?

Tags: windows, filesystems, network-share

Sometimes it happens that I want to rename/delete a file on a network share, but Windows tells me that the file is currently in use, even if I know that nobody else is accessing that file. After waiting some seconds/minutes I can rename/delete the file without any problems.

Is there any default time-out for file locks on Windows network shares? If yes, how large is it and is it possible to change it?

Comment: How are you sure that nobody else is using the file? What about processes local to the server (AV, replication, backups, etc..)?

Comment: @GregL: Ultimately only a server-side check about open file handles would tell this. But nonetheless I encountered this situation way too often, so I was wondering if there is any mechanism (caching, time-out, ...) that would keep a lock on a file on a network share, even if all "connections" to that file had been closed.